# Index Only File Names For Windows Explorer Search?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, indexing-service

How can one tell Windows to index only file names under Windows?

Running a `name:*whatever*` search in `Windows Explorer` takes a long time without indexing the entire file system.  That is overkill for those of us merely interested in getting the equivalent speed of Linux `updatedb` and `locate` without relying on 3rd party applications.

Answer (score 1):

Simple: Just use 3rd party tools like `updatedb` and `locate` (like you are doing under linux). A default Linux search with `find -i name` would be as slow as explorer's method.

Thew most simple one I know (and already delivered delivered with windows) is `where`.

```
C:\>where format.*
C:\Windows\System32\format.com
```

But if you're fond of the command line, you may want to look at powershell too. To accomplish the same type of search you'd use

```
PS F:\> get-childitem c:\ -filter format.* -recurse
```

Which has the nice side benefit of being able to be pumped into a objectorized foreach statement, run a process against the search results or do stuff with the objects properties.